Need help to find SMD IC Mark as "E83J and 91"
Need help to find SMD  IC Mark as "E83J " 3Pin and IC "91J" 10 Pin
I cant find it online,maybe someone have advice for me


It's BL8552 1.8V Low comsumption Linear Regulator IC
91J is TLA 2024 12bit ADC
